# Write expressions in simpler form with substitution for part of the epxression

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I have faced this situation many times where I get values like this as solutions:

```
x = (a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7) * (a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7) * m
y = (a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7) * (a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6 - a7) * n
```

Now, the value for `x` and `y` has `(a1 + a1 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7)` and `a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6` as common parts. Is there any built-in way to detect these common parts in Mathematica and write solutions like:

```
x = p * (q + a7) * m
y = p * (q - a7) * n

where p = (a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7) and q = a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6
```

If there is no automatic way of doing this, can I tell Mathematica to substitute these values manually?

Comment: Try this: `x /. {a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5 a6 -> p, a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5 a6 + a7 -> q}` and the same for `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexei Boulbitch's comment is great, so I will elaborate on it. The `/.` stands for the function ReplaceAll, which, according to the [Wolfram Documentation page for it](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

> applies a rule or list of rules in an attempt to transform each subpart of an expression *expr*.

In this case, you would like to replace the expression `a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7` with `p` and the expression  `a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7` with `q`. The corresponding rules are  `a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7 -> p` and `a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6 -> q`. Put the rules in a list and use them with `ReplaceAll`, either by writing

```
ReplaceAll[x, {a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7 -> p, a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6 -> q}]
```

or

```
x /. {a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5*a6 + a7 -> p, a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5*a6 -> q}
```